# Solution set to $n^{2p-1}\leq 2^{n(1-p)}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For what positive, real values of $p$ and positive, integer values of $n$ does the inequality
$$
n^{2p-1}\leq 2^{n(1-p)}
$$
hold? I tried using logarithms but got nowhere.

It comes from me trying to compare this series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n(p-1)}n^{2p}}
$$
to the harmonic series for convergence, and the above series comes from applying the Cauchy condensation test to
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n\ln^{2}(n))^p}
$$

Comment: The original series is quite a bit easier to work with.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you please elaborate? Did I take a wrong step by applying the Cauchy condensation test?

Comment: No wrong step. If you want to use Cauchy Condensation, then *all that matters*  is behaviour for large $n$, so asking for explicit combinations of $n$ and $p$ is unnecessary, and quite difficult.  Also, here the integral test and comparisons are easier to apply.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I tried the integral test, but I couldn't integrate the function for $p\neq 1$, and I tried the comparison test with the standard $p$-series, which works for $p>1$, but not for $0<p\leq1$.

Comment: If $p=1$ we get convergence, if $p\lt 1$ divergence (limit comparison).

Comment: @AndréNicolas For the limit comparison test in $p<1$, I compared it to the harmonic series, but I got the limit of the quotients to be $0$, which is inconclusive since the harmonic series diverges for $p<1$.

Comment: If $p\lt 1$, let $p=1-\alpha$. Now use the fact that any power of $\log n$ goes to infinity more slowly than $n^{\alpha/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to know when $n^{2p-1}\leq 2^{n(1-p)}$, and care mostly about high values of $n$.  Let's leave aside $p=1$, which is really easy ($n\leq 1$).

Let's take logarithms.  We get $\log(n^{2p-1})\leq \log(2^{n(1-p)})$, i.e., $(2p-1)\log n $ $\le (\log 2)n(1-p)$, or $${2p-1\over (1-p)\log 2}\leq {n\over\log n}$$ when $1-p$ is positive.

For $0<p\le 1/2$ the LHS is $\le 0$ and the RHS positive except for $n=1$, so the inequality is always satisfied.

For $1/2< p < 1$, the LHS is positive and goes to infinity as $p$ goes to $1$, but for large enough $n$ and fixed $p$, the RHS is always greater.

For $p>1$, then $1-p$ is negative and the inequality goes in the opposite direction from that stated above.  The LHS is again negative, while the RHS is positive except for $n=1$, so the inequality is not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Is it obvious that $n/\log n$ is unbounded?

Comment: I'd rather say "known" than "obvious," but $n/\log n=\exp(\log n)/\log n$.  We have $\exp(x)\ge 1+x+x^2/2$ for positive $x$ by the Taylor series, so we get that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \exp(x)/x = \infty$.  Since $\log n$ goes to $\infty$ when $n$ does, we get that $n/\log n\to\infty$.  But I made a mistake and need to fix it

Comment: Oh, I see. But the $1-p>0$ is the only case I really cared about anyway. Thanks a lot! :)